# OOP Web scraper using regex to grab tag contents

Tags: object-oriented, php5, web-scraping

I'm about learning about implementing [the solid principle](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/the-solid-principles--cms-634) in PHP.

I want to create simple content crawler/grabber from some websites. This crawler will grab the content from the website url. Since we know that every website has different html tag structure, so I created an interface.

```
<?php

interface BotInterface
{

    public function tembakURL();

    public function parseBody();
}
```

Then implemented the interface into child class. My plan is to create a class for every website. Here's an example.

```
<?php

class BotYogyes implements BotInterface
{

    protected $rest;
    protected $url;
    protected $body;

    public function __construct($url, \GuzzleHttp\Client $rest) {
        $this->rest = $rest;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function tembakURL() {
        $response = $this->rest->get($this->url);
        $code = $response->getStatusCode();
        $body = $response->getBody();
        if ($code == 200) {
            $this->body = $body;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Gagal menembak url [$code]");
        }
    }

    public function parseBody() {
        $html = implode('', $this->unfoldLines($this->body));
        #judul
        preg_match_all('/\<h1\>(.*)\<div\sclass="social\-share"\>/', $html, $header, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        preg_match_all('/\<h1\>(.*)\<\/h1\>/', $header[0][0], $judul, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        preg_match_all('/\<p\sclass="address"\>(.*?)\s\(\<a/', $header[0][0], $alamat, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        preg_match_all('/\<p\sclass="meta\-description"\>(.*?)\<\/p>/', $header[0][0], $deskripsi, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        #konten
        preg_match_all('/\<div\sid="photo\-gallery\-mini"\>(.*)\<\!\-\-\sinsertRelatedArticle\(\)\s\-\-\>/', $html, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        preg_match_all('/\<p\>(.*?)\<\/p\>/', $match[0][0], $paragraf, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        #peta
        preg_match_all('/\<p\sclass="address"\>GPS\sCoordinate:\s\<a[^\>]*\>(.*?)\<\/a\>\<\/p\>/', $html, $peta, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        file_put_contents('/vagrant/tmp/anarky.txt', var_export(array($judul, $alamat, $deskripsi, $paragraf, $peta), true));
    }

    private function unfoldLines($content) {
        $data = array();
        $content = explode("\n", $content);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
            $line = rtrim($content[$i]);
            while (isset($content[$i + 1]) && strlen($content[$i + 1]) > 0 && ($content[$i + 1]{0} == ' ' || $content[$i + 1]{0} == "\t" )) {
                $line .= rtrim(substr($content[++$i], 1));
            }
            $data[] = $line;
        }
        return $data;
    }

}
```

This how the classes will be used:

```
<?php
try {
            $rest = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $sync = new BotYogyes('http://website.to/grab/content', $rest);
            $sync->tembakURL();
            $sync->parseBody();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            watchdog('bot_yogyes', $e->getMessage(), null, WATCHDOG_ERROR, null);
        }
```

These code blocks work properly, but, am I it doing right?